# NIntegrate::ncvbr: How should we interpret and handle this error not mentioned in any documentation?

Tags: numerical-integration, warning-messages, version-10, mesh, regions

I have some user-defined module describing my integrand which has to be computed numerically (it's much more complicated than this but bear with me):

```
foo[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] := Module[{f}, f = x+y+z; Return[f]];
```

Then I have a `region` I am defining with a rotated, truncated polyhedron, and using that as my integration domain which is a new V10 feature:

```
<< PolyhedronOperations`
polys = Flatten[Normal[Truncate[PolyhedronData["Octahedron", "Faces"], 1/3]], 1];
p1 = Polygon[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, Sqrt[3/2]/2 - 1/(2 Sqrt[6]), 1/Sqrt[3]}, {-(1/(2 Sqrt[2])), -(1/(2 Sqrt[6])), 1/Sqrt[3]}, {1/(2 Sqrt[2]), -(1/(2 Sqrt[6])), 1/Sqrt[3]}}];
p2 = Polygon[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}/2, {0, 1, 1}/2, {1, 0, 1}/2}];
m = Last@FindGeometricTransform[p1, p2];
rot = Flatten[Table[m[polys[[i, 1]]], {i, 1, 14}], 1];
region = ConvexHullMesh[rot];
```

Then when I `NIntegrate` over it, I get an error which *doesn't exist yet* in the Wolfram documentation, or on Google, or anywhere:

```
NIntegrate[foo[x, y, z], {x, y, z} ∈ region]

NIntegrate::ncvbr: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 5 refinements. NIntegrate obtained 0.35562326340448547` and 0.03672493677717351` for the integral and error estimates. >>
```

(Those numbers will change if you use the simple foo function.) The link in the error (>>) just takes me to the NIntegrate documentation. So my question is:

**What precisely does the `ncvbr` error mean?**

The error tag which seems related is `ncvb`, for example this is from the `NIntegrate` documentation:

```
NIntegrate::ncvb: "NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in x near {x} = {9.43625271977563}. NIntegrate obtained 10.3032-6.74255i and 0.3168981771605228` for the integral and error estimates. >>
```

which is actually informative, and says I need to crank up `MinRecursion` and `MaxRecursion`.

However since I am using a `ConvexHullMesh` to specify my domain, could the way Mathematica "tetrahedralizes" my `region` be the problem instead, since `ncvbr` specifically mentions "refinement?"

Would playing with `Min/MaxRecursions` even access this new feature, or do I have to manually refine my own mesh to prepare my integration domain? It seems like an unnecessary pain that should be accessible through the `NIntegrate` options.

Comment: Hard to say without the real `f`. Try "bmesh = NDSolve`FEM`ToBoundaryMesh[rot];NIntegrate[foo[x, y, z], {x, y, z} \[Element] bmesh]" and see if that helps.

Comment: @user21, the original foo wasn't included so the Q/A could be sufficiently general. My focus is more on the meaning of the error as it pertains to the new region functionality, and how NIntegrate performs meshing and refinement. As far as I can gather through other errors, it 1) Needs symbolic processing on to recognize the region, and 2) Uses the TetGenLink library to mesh it. Also, I am integrating the interior & boundary of my region, not just the boundary, but it gives me a good clue, so I thank you.

Comment: I apologize, I checked again and it is indeed integrating the interior as well. Is NIntegrate allowed to refine the mesh, or does it set it in stone? Let's say my foo is well-behaved, but has small numbers and is finely detailed, can I rest assured my answer is accurate?

Comment: `NIntegrate` uses adaptive refinement. How and if stuff is refined depends on the convergence of `f`. I am not quite sure I understand the question you have.

Comment: I suppose my question reflects the limits of my understanding on how regions are treated. I was skeptical because now the integrals run *very* fast compared to what I posted and former methods, and without complaints about convergence, and it only makes me suspicious because it seems too good to be true!

Comment: OK, if you want to control adaptive refinement in this (region) case you can use a `MaxRecursion` setting. If you directly give `NIntegrate` a mesh (ElementMesh) that is second order `NIntegrate` can not use adaptive refinement as it can not know to refine a possibly curved boundary. A linear mesh (`ElementMesh` or `BoundaryMeshRegion` or `MeshRegion`) will trigger adaptive refinement. Try using the region and slowly crank up `MaxRecursion` and see how the result behaves.